# How to access dynamic attribute 'geo_near_distance' with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid3

I am using Mongoid 3.1.6 with Rails 4. I need to find all the objects 'near' a certain co-ordinate. For each result from the search, I will need to display the distance from the search co-orodinate. According to Mongoid [Documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/querying.html#geo_near)

> ...each instantiated document from a $geoNear query will get a special
>   dynamic attribute geo_near_distance that will be available as long as
>   the document is in memory.

But I am not able to access the `Object.geo_near_distance`

My query inside controller...

```
@objects = Object.geo_near([-118.4451, 34.0633]).max_distance(10)
```

Edit#1

Some additional details

If the use the following query in MongoDB

```
db.runCommand( { geoNear: "objects",
             near: [ -73.95269,40.77578],
             spherical: true
           })
```

I see an array of 100 elements. Each element has 2 attributes. The first one, 'dis' has values like '0.000123' (Note: this is not in Km or Mile) and the second attribute is the result Object itself.

Now I have changed the query to Mongoid to...

```
@objects = Object.geo_near([-118.4451, 34.0633]).spherical.max_distance(10)
```

still no result.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After more than 2 years, the issue ticket is still open on mongodb jira tracker.

The quick fix is not use the hash notation instead of the dot notation to access the attribute:

Instead of

```
Object.geo_near_distance
```

Use

```
Object['geo_near_distance']
```

Tested on mongoid 6

Comment: I was looking all over for this

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the field while you are iterating the documents? You can see by the specs that this field is in fact there when the document is in memory and is being part of the iteration of the criteria result.

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/spec/mongoid/contextual/geo_near_spec.rb#L167